# Firebase not working on React Native version 53

Tags: firebase, react-native

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-firebase:javaPreCompileDebug'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-firebase:debugCompileClasspath'.
>   Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:{strictly 3.6.0}.
>        Required by:
>            project :react-native-firebase
>   Cannot find a version of 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' that satisfies the version constraints: 
>              Dependency path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.53.3' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
>              Constraint path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:{strictly 3.6.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.6.0
>              Constraint path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:{strictly 3.6.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.6.0
>              Dependency path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:17.0.2' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0'
>              Dependency path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:17.0.0' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.1'
>              Constraint path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:{strictly 3.6.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.6.0
>              Constraint path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:{strictly 3.6.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.6.0
>              Dependency path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.53.3' --> 'com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:1.3.0' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
>              Dependency path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.53.3' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.6.0' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
>              Constraint path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:{strictly 3.6.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.6.0
>              Constraint path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:{strictly 3.6.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.6.0
>              Constraint path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:{strictly 3.6.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.6.0
>              Constraint path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:{strictly 3.6.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.6.0
>              Constraint path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:{strictly 3.6.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.6.0
>              Constraint path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:{strictly 3.6.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.6.0
>              Constraint path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:{strictly 3.6.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.6.0
>              Constraint path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:{strictly 3.6.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.6.0
>
> Could not resolve com.squareup.okio:okio:{strictly 1.13.0}.
>        Required by:
>            project :react-native-firebase
>   Cannot find a version of 'com.squareup.okio:okio' that satisfies the version constraints:
>              Dependency path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.53.3' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0'
>              Constraint path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:{strictly 1.13.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.13.0
>              Constraint path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:{strictly 1.13.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.13.0
>              Constraint path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:{strictly 1.13.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.13.0
>              Constraint path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:{strictly 1.13.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.13.0
>              Constraint path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:{strictly 1.13.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.13.0
>              Constraint path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:{strictly 1.13.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.13.0
>              Constraint path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:{strictly 1.13.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.13.0
>              Constraint path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:{strictly 1.13.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.13.0
>              Dependency path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.53.3' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.1' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0'
>              Dependency path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.2' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'
>              Dependency path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.2' --> 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.21.0' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0'
>              Constraint path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:{strictly 1.13.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.13.0
>              Constraint path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:{strictly 1.13.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.13.0
>              Constraint path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:{strictly 1.13.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.13.0
>              Constraint path 'fps:react-native-firebase:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okio:okio:{strictly 1.13.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.13.0

Answer (score 0):

put `com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true` at the end of your `build.grandle`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are installing the compatible firebase plugin version in app. This is happen mostly when there will be different google services version available in same app. (Please refer this [link](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/tree/v5.1.1) for version compatibility ) I was also facing similar issues by installing correct version I solved my problems.